# Sorting select with cast

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

Is it possible to do special formatted order in c#?
I have *.json file with data like

```
{
  "RECORDS": [
    {
      "ROWW": "279166",
      "ALBUMID": "3",
      "LINK": "https://...1"
    },
    {
      "ROWW": "279165",
      "ALBUMID": "1",
      "LINK": "https://...2"
    },
    {
      "ROWW": "279164",
      "ALBUMID": "2",
      "LINK": "https://...3"
    }]
}
```

... a lot of records. And I need to get DataRows ordered by Roww casted like number.

That's How I trying to do this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
//...

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public class RECORD_PHOTO
        {
            public string ROWW { get; set; }
            public string ALBUMID { get; set; }
            public string LINK { get; set; }
        }

        public class PhotoObject
        {
            public List<RECORD_PHOTO> RECORDS { get; set; }
        }
        
        public List<string[]> listForJson = new List<string[]>();
        
        public List<String> PHOTO_Rows = new List<String>();
        public List<String> PHOTO_AlbumIds = new List<String>();
        public List<String> PHOTO_Links = new List<String>();

        string JsonFileName = @"C:\temp_work\test.json"

        public DataTable dtFromJson;
    
        private void Starting()
        {
            string jsonn = File.OpenText(JsonFileName).ReadToEnd();
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PhotoObject>(JsonFileName);
            PHOTO_Rows = result.RECORDS.Select(p => p.ROWW).ToList();
            PHOTO_AlbumIds = result.RECORDS.Select(p => p.ALBUMID).ToList();
            PHOTO_Links = result.RECORDS.Select(p => p.LINK).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < PHOTO_Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                listForJson.Add(new string[] { PHOTO_Rows[i], PHOTO_AlbumIds[i], PHOTO_Links[i]});
            }
            dtFromJson = ConvertListToDataTable(VKPH);
            dtFromJson.Columns[0].ColumnName = "ROWW";
            dtFromJson.Columns[1].ColumnName = "ALBUMID";
            dtFromJson.Columns[2].ColumnName = "LINK";
            //
            DataRow[] rows = dtFromJson.Select("", "ROWW ASC");                   
        }
    }
}
```

But Sorting in Select by "ROWW" worked like String so I need to add some cast like:

```
DataRow[] rows = dtFromJson.Select("", "TO_NUMBER(ROWW) ASC");
```

But this is wrong

Comment: dtFromJson = dtFromJson.AsEnumberable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("ALBUMID")).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: @jdweng still doesn't work, result looks like:
<"1", "10", "100", ...>
when expecting 
<"1","2","3", ...>

Thanks for trying

Comment: Then try one of following : 1) dtFromJson = dtFromJson.AsEnumberable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<int>("ALBUMID")).CopyToDataTable(); 2) dtFromJson = dtFromJson.AsEnumberable().OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Field<string>("ALBUMID"))).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: @Vladjkaaa I am confused you want data to be in order like <"1", "2", "3"> however ordering by ROWW would result in <"2", "1", "3">. I think ALBUMID and ROWW are mixed up here in the example

Comment: @ZachHutchins albumids doesn't matter for ordering, they loading in random order but rows for links must be ASC

Answer (score 1):

The `DataColumn.Expression` property can be used to add another column to the table that maintains an int version of your ROWW column:

```
dtFromJson.Columns.Add("ROWWint", typeof(int)).Expression = "CONVERT([ROWW], 'System.Int32')";
```

You can then orderby this column in your Select

```
DataRow[] rows = dtFromJson.Select("", "ROWWint");
```

See it in action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cuh2np

--

You could also query the row collection using LINQ:

```
dtFromJson = dtFromJson.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32((string)x["ROWW"])).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sort by ROWW just like number then try below piece of code:

```
string jsonn = File.OpenText(JsonFileName).ReadToEnd();

//Your code modified. Initially it was reading file name . 
//Now reading json string from file.
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PhotoObject>(jsonn);

//Sort by ROWW after converting to int.
var sortedByRowwResult = result.RECORDS.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.ROWW)).ToList();
```

After this you can put into data table. But please check your requirement. Is it really required to put json into datatable?